# Hadoop setfacl via Scala/Java

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to do hdfs dfs -setfacl via Scala/Java? Doing it via hdfs shell is slow.

e.g. I would like to rewrite this:
Seq("hdfs", "dfs", "-setfacl", "-R", "-m", "group:hive:rwx", s"$targetTableFolderPath/$targetPartitionValue").!!

into Scala code. Is there a method on fs: FileSystem that I could call? How?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use hadoop API. Here are the (java)docs for the HdfsAdmin class:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/